# Is it possible to have my Google Drive documents on my desktop some how?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-docs

I have about 20 documents on my Google Drive that I constantly and continuously edit.

Is there a way to have quick access to them from my desktop?

I use to just pin them in my browser but I can not read the title this way.

Comment: what "title" ? can you explain?

Comment: In the browser each tab has a title so you know what URL/Title is in it.

Comment: hovering the cursor over the tab will reveal you the title - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrfuQ.png

Comment: which browser is  that?

Comment: Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Google Drive sync software,
And place the synchronization folder on the desktop.

Comment: Interesting but I don't want the documents physically on my desktop just pointers or links to the cloud version.

Comment: So the only solution is to create a link on the desktop for each document separately.
And write the title of the document in the name of the link.

Comment: @J.M. this is the correct solution. The files that are synced are shortcuts to the online versions. The files that are synced are only 1KB.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you sync your computer's Desktop with the computer folder on your Google Drive storage, using Backup and Sync. Then, add the folder in your Drive with your Google Docs to your desktop by selecting the folder, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, then add it to Computers > *Your computer name* > Desktop. You can also do this for individual files, or for several files that you've selected.

These Google Doc files on your Desktop will be shortcuts to the web pages where the files are (the files that are synced are only 1KB in size).

Answer (score 0):

You could enable offline editing which will kind of mimic what you want:

[image: 0]

But you can also download them:

[image: 0]

Comment: That "available offline" ... is that for mobile or do desktop browsers show that as well?

Comment: @J.M. it's for desktops too

Comment: I can't find it.

Comment: those 3 dots you show on your screenshot don't appear to exist on the **desktop** version and nor does the option to use offline.

Comment: @J.M. I am on desktop PC >>> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmY7Z.png